# Why does CFD over predict shockwave in comparison to wind tunnel?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics, cfd

I ran a CFD simulation of Mach=0.85 flow over an aerofoil and noted that my Cp (coefficient of pressure) plot over predicts the shockwave in comparison to experimental data?

Can someone please explain why?

Parameters:
Turbulence model: k-w sst
Discretisation: third order

[image]

Comment: Experimental is accurate for the actual conditions, models have assumptions that affect accuracy. Got told of a wing that was subjected to experimental stress loading - failed within about 5cm of the predicted failure point. Which was more accurate??

Answer (score 0):

Were the experimental data adjusted for wind tunnel conditions? Wind tunnel experiment have different boundary conditions than 2-d airfoil in cfd.